# Mac: Create one virtual audio device out of the combination of others

Tags: macos, mac, audio, dj

So I have just realized, that my `Traktor Audio 6` would use EVERY and ANY *input* labeled device as an input...well, duh, how could I think it'd only use the MAIN in's and out's.

But now I have the problem that, when I am live DJing, people can hear the beep-noise from my Timecode Vinyls...which is annoying.

So my question would be, is it possible to create a virtual audio device in Mac OS, by combining the in's and out's - especially the in's of another device?

Like...

```
Streaming Device (2 in / 0 out)
| - Traktor A6: Main Left
| - Traktor A6: Main Right
```

That'd be super helpful so I dont have to play around with mixer volumes and alike. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar with the sort of application you're describing, but you can create “Aggregate Devices” using Audio MIDI Setup, which sounds like it might be helpful.

1. Open [image: Applications → Utilities → Audio MIDI Setup.]
2. Click the + button and select “Create Aggregate Device”.
3. Use the right side panel to choose which existing inputs you want to aggregate.

I've never used this feature, so I have no idea whether it does what you want. If it's completely irrelevant, let me know and I'll delete this answer.

[image: (screenshot)]

(Also, you might be interested to know that there is a Stack Exchange site specifically for [Audio-Video Production](http://avp.stackexchange.com).)

Comment: I know of this programm - however, it'll combine __all__ ins and outs and not just a selection of channels.
However, thanks for trying to help :)